# File Path for Source Property not work properly

Tags: wpf, filepath

I have "WPF userControl Library" project. In it I have window which has next line of code

```
   <Image  x:Name="imgInstructionIcon" Source="images/InfoIcon.png" >
```

and also in project I have "images" folder which contains InfoIcon.png file. But My code didn't see this file  and give next error:

> Error 58  The file images/InfoIcon.png is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' property is not set to 'Resource'

When I change path to the `Source=../images/InfoIcon.png` I see my icon in designer but not see in runtime.
My project is part of Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the uri pack syntac - Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Set the Source="images/InfoIcon.png", BuildAction to Resource and compile the application. Now you can see in designer as well as runtime.

Comment: Okay whether the Xaml & image files are in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing as the error says: select the image in the solution explorer, then in the properties set the build action to resource. It should fix your problem.

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried adding it to the project default resx file and using it from there?